# bold certain words from field crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a description field that I want to bold only certain words from the database. Crystal Reports 8  For every time the word "Phenolic" is in the description, I want that word to be bold.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field and declare a string variable into that formula field.

```
stringvar sHTML := {@field} ;
sHTML := Replace(sHTML,"Phenolic", "<span style='font-weight:bold'>Phenolic</span>");
```

place that formula field wherever you want to place then right click on that formula field and select format object go tot Paragraph Tab and select HTML Text from Text Interpretation option.